# How to run function on document ready after sorting? JQuery

Tags: jquery, onclicklistener

I have a div containing multiple tables. Each table has a delete button that calls a function to delete the table. The tables can also be sorted ascending/descending by date. The delete function will work but not if the table has been sorted.

[JSFiddle Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CZmCZ/)

The delete button looks like this.

```
 <button id="6" class="delete">X</button>
```

The function has a click event listener for the 'delete' class. I'm currently only displaying the id using alert for debugging purposes.

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

I suspect the reason it doesn't work after sorting is because it gets the ID attribute using the `$(this)` selector and this is not specific enough after sorting.

I have tried various means to pass the table ID to the delete function but none will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reappending the content when sorting, making the `.delete` elements dynamic, and for that you would need a delegated event handler:

```
$("#meetingTable").on('click', ".delete", function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CZmCZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Put an additional copy or a callback to your delete function within your button sort function right after this line

```
    sortUsingNestedText($('#meetingTable'), "table", $(this).data("sortKey"));
```

I tested it works.

Answer (score -1):

try changing

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
```

with

```
$(".delete").on("click", function(){
```

This will allow jQuery to listen out for clicks on that element even after DOM manipulation

Comment: Those two statements are logically equivalent.

Comment: Do I mean `.live("click", function()`?

Comment: Nope, that's not what you meant, as live() is removed.